# How should I handle endianness with the enet network library?

Tags: c++, networking, network-programming

The website of the enet c++ network library states that it makes "no assumptions about endianness"

so..... what would be the best way to convert the data i'm sending over enet to network byte order and back??

thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably what your library writer wants you to know is that they do not assume a particular host endianess and they convert between host and network byte order as necessary. But you are still free to choose the most convenient endianess for your data bytes.

Comment: ok.... thanks to everyone!

Maybe I've to test first whether enet really makes no conversions.

I've an arm machine  (raspberry pi) with big endian  which should be perfekt for testing...

Answer (score 0):

Pick a byte order for your protocol messages and apply it consistently. Little endian may be more convenient since intel processors are typically configured for little endian.
There is no particular reason for you to choose network byte order.